# Is it possible to use a non-default bridge network when running CodeBuild locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild, docker-network, localstack

When I run codebuild locally it creates the default docker network and volumes as in the below output. Is there a way to use different bridge network and volumes instead of these default ones? I tried modifying the docker command in [codebuild_build.sh](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/local_builds/codebuild_build.sh) to add a network (below build command output shows `--network mylocaltestingnetwork`) but that didn't help as such.

The reason I am trying to use a different network and volumes is because I am using [localstack](https://localstack.cloud/) along with it, and the bridge network and volumes need to be accessible from the codebuild local container.

If I configure my localstack to use the `agent-resources_default` network created by local codebuild then codebuild is able to access localstack. But, I would like to keep the dependency external to both codebuild and localstack by using a separate bridge network.

```
$ ./codebuild_build.sh -i public.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0 -a codebuild-output/ -b buildspec-local.yml -c -p localstack

Build Command:

docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e "IMAGE_NAME=public.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0" -e "ARTIFACTS=<repo path>/codebuild-output/" --network mylocaltestingnetwork -e "SOURCE=<repo path>" -e "BUILDSPEC=<repo path>/buildspec-local.yml" -e "AWS_CONFIGURATION=<homedir>/.aws" -e "AWS_PROFILE=localstack" -e "INITIATOR=<user>" public.ecr.aws/codebuild/local-builds:latest


Removing network agent-resources_default
Removing volume agent-resources_source_volume
Removing volume agent-resources_user_volume
Creating network "agent-resources_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "agent-resources_source_volume" with local driver
Creating volume "agent-resources_user_volume" with local driver
Creating agent-resources_agent_1 ... done
Creating agent-resources_build_1 ... done
Attaching to agent-resources_agent_1, agent-resources_build_1
agent_1  | [Container] 2022/01/14 15:57:15 Waiting for agent ping
agent_1  | [Container] 2022/01/14 15:57:17 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
agent_1  | [Container] 2022/01/14 15:57:23 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
```